# Django many-to-many save

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I'm writing a news page for a website, and have two models with a Many-To-Many relationship: Tags and Posts.
Now, I want to display the most popular tags on each page, and to avoid counting the amount of Many-To-Many relationship links each time a user visits a page, I store a counter for each Tag. My idea was to modify the "save" method for Post to increase that counter.
Here's the code for these two models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_text = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Tag')
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag_text

class Post(models.Model):

    IS_DRAFT = (("Y", "Draft post"), ("N", "Finished post"),)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True, blank=True)
    text = RichTextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Created on')
    last_edited_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Last edited on', db_index=True)
    draft = models.CharField(choices=IS_DRAFT, max_length=1, verbose_name='Is a post draft')
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            date = datetime.now()
            tr_title = unicode(unidecode(self.title))
            self.slug = '%i/%i/%i/%s' % (
                date.year, date.month, date.day, slugify(tr_title)
            )
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'count', self.tag.count()
        for t in self.tag.all():
            print 'tag amount', t.amount
            t.amount += 1
            t.save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I added the prints in the save method for testing purposes, because, for some reason, the line

```
print 'count', self.tag.count()
```

outputs 0 (as if no tags are assigned to this model instance).
However, printing out any other field during the save method works fine. For example:

```
print 'title', self.title
```

outputs the title, so it's not a problem with accessing the model fields.
Is there something I can do about this? Or will I have to resort to doing the stuff I want to with the help of signals?

Answer (score 1):

ManyToManyField items can't be added to a model until after it's been saved.

Your code doesn't show where your creating the model from, so it's not clear where the best place to put the counter in is.

Basically you need to modify what ever method adds the tags, not the method which saves the post which is run before tags are added.

Edit: One simple option would be to explicitly define the through model for the ManyToMany relationship, then you could modify it's save method and do the incrementing there: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: I create the models in the admin only. I'll try doing what you said with the through model.